# google drive file missing

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, loss, data-files

There is a data file stored in Google Cloud Disk. The data file contains 25,000 pictures. At the beginning of the operation, 25,000 pictures can be read, and then after a few hours, only 2,900 pictures can be read when running again. The picture file will not be read every time. Complete, can only be re-uploaded once, I have not deleted it

I uploaded it again, and after reading it, there were still 25,000 pictures. But when I tried to read it again after a few hours, there were 21,000 pictures left. I hope that the data in the google drive and mydrive folders can be complete.